# Unable to access Redis (cluster mode enabled) Cluster's Endpoints

Tags: redis, amazon-elasticache, redis-cluster, redis-cli

I have 1 VPC - under that 1 EC2 instance ( amazon ami ) and 1 Redis (cluster mode enabled) Cluster with Auth ( password) and with Security Group Open to all IP:Port ( only for testing sake ) - so very simple setup.

telnet works at port 6379 from my EC2 Instance 
- Configuration EndPoint
- Shard>eachNode EndPoint

Not able to connect to Redis Server using Redis CLI - doesnt matter endpoint either Config or Node endpoint; Using Redis CLI of v.5.0.4 ;

Please Note - AWS ElastiCache Redis Cluster ( Cluster disabled ) or Single Server Node, provides Primary Endpoint, which works fine. Only when Cluster is enabled and get ConfigEndpoint/NodeEndPoints - then having problem.

Config EndPoint:

```
[root@ip-xx-xx-xx-xx src]# ./redis-cli -h clustercfg.xxxx.xxxxx.use1.cache.amazonaws.com  -p 6379
```

Node EndPoint:

```
[root@ip-xx-xx-xx-xx src]# ./redis-cli -h xxxx-0001-0-01.xxxx.xxxxx.use1.cache.amazonaws.com  -p 6379
```

Any help is appreciated!

thanks

Answer (score 1):

After spending few days on this issue, I was able to find the solution - we need stunnel or any other equivalent that creates SSL tunnel, redis-cli doesn't support ssl or tls.

> To access data from ElastiCache for Redis nodes enabled with in-transit encryption, you use clients that work with Secure Socket Layer (SSL). However, redis-cli doesn't support SSL or Transport Layer Security (TLS).
>   To work around this, you can use the stunnel command to create an SSL tunnel to the redis nodes. You then use redis-cli to connect to the tunnel to access data from encrypted Redis nodes.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/red-ug/in-transit-encryption.html

Comment: It seems your solution relates to applying encryption to your cluster, not to enabling cluster-mode.